# how to remove mysql error #1064?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

MySQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE FC_Categories (
CategoryID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
CategoryName VARCHAR( 15 ) ,
Description TEXT,
Picture LONGBLOB,
UNIQUE (
CategoryName
),
PRIMARY KEY ( CategoryID )
) TYPE = MYISAM ;
```

MySQL error after running query:

```
Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 8
```

Comment: It is not good solution to store pictures in db...

Comment: Missing ` in (CategoryID` ) ) TYPE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Type` is obsolete now, and hence is the error.

Use `Engine=MyISAM`

Answer (score 1):

please use `ENGINE=MyISAM` instead.

Answer (score 0):

replace  `TYPE=MyISAM` to `ENGINE=MyISAM`